# Static IP on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, ethernet, static-ip

How can I set up a static IP on my Arch Linux installation so I can easily SSH in?

I followed [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=54080), but I *could not* get the static IP I set to work! Here's my `/etc/netctl/eth0` file:

```
Description='A simple ethernet connection using a static IP'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('192.168.1.5/24')
```

Can anyone see what my problem is and/or point/give me to a good tutorial on how to set this up?

DHCP isn't a huge problem, just a little slower, because I have to look up  the IP via the router.

**EDIT**: Trying @syb0rg's solution:

I worked through the solution up to the `netctl start eth0` part, and then it threw an error:

`$ sudo netctl start eth0`

```
Job for netctl@eth0.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@eth0.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

`$ systemctl status netctl@eth0.service`

```
netctl@eth0.service - Networking for netctl profile eth0
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 1969-12-31 19:12:12 EST; 21s ago
     Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
  Process: 316 ExecStart=/usr/lib/network/network start %I (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 316 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

`journalctl -xn`

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 1969-12-31 19:00:32 EST, end at Wed 1969-12-31 19:10:43 EST
Dec 31 19:08:49 ArchPiServer systemd[294]: Stopped target Sound Card.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/catalog/9d1aa
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished shutting down.
Dec 31 19:08:49 ArchPiServer systemd[294]: Starting Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has begun starting up.
Dec 31 19:08:49 ArchPiServer systemd[294]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Dec 31 19:08:49 ArchPiServer systemd[294]: Startup finished in 830ms.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
-- 
-- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Userspace start-up required 830163 microseconds.
Dec 31 19:10:43 ArchPiServer sudo[301]: pam_unix(sudo:account): account server-g
```

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change directories to access the network settings:

```
# cd /etc/netctl
# cp examples/ethernet-static ./eth0
```

We need to edit the configuration file, `etch0`, and add in the settings we need. Before you proceed, you will need the following:

- Static IP address – I’m using `192.168.1.36`. The netmask I’m using
  is `255.255.255.0` which is defined as "/24" or the first 24 bits.
- An Interface name – I’m using `eth0`.
- A default gateway – I use `192.168.1.1`.
- Some DNS names servers – I’m using `8.8.8.8` and `194.168.4.100` and
  `194.168.8.100` – which are Google and Virgin Media’s DNS servers. You should use the ones you have been told to use by your own ISP.

When you have finished editing the file, it should look like the following, using the settings above:

```
Description='Anything you like'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('192.168.1.36/24')
gateway=('192.168.1.1')
DNS=('8.8.8.8' '194.168.4.100' '194.168.8.100')
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Try starting the network:

```
# netctl start eth0
```

**Note:** On my system, that always returns an error, but the networking actually begins working.

---

After this, I can ping `8.8.8.8` and also ping `google.com` and in both cases, get a correct response.

If your network starts ok, without error, and works, then you can configure it to always start on boot by running the following command:

```
# netctl enable eth0
```

If you ever decide to disable it again, it’s equally as simple:

```
# netctl disable eth0
```

Comment: I noticed you spelled `gateway` with lowercase instead of `Gateway`. This was actually the solution for me. This is how I realized, that I should just leave out `Gateway=` (or comment it), which has the same effect as a bad spelling. I'm not sure if it was just a typo, but if it is, it solved my problem! I guess on an ethernet connection you usually don't really need to specify a gateway.

Answer (score 4):

You would be better to set your router to serve a static IP to the Pi.
This way you can easily use the Pi on other networks, and avoid problems with duplicate IP

Answer (score 4):

You have to add

```
AutoWired=yes
```

to your static config in order to get it to work.

Here's a tutorial:
http://blog.pixxis.be/post/77298179924/setting-up-a-static-ip-on-arch-linux

Comment: Can you perhaps fix the dead link?

Answer (score 2):

All of these solutions didn't work for me. I fixed it by doing this:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
```

remove the line that says

```
DHCP=yes
```

then, make sure your `[Network]` part looks like this:

```
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.40/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

Of course, replace the values of Address and Gateway by the values you desire. Reboot your device.